# Current month and last month data in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following table has datatypes as follows:

ItemName varchar, Date Date, Amt varchar, status varchar

```
ItemName        Date        Amt     

    ABC       1/02/2012     500     
    ABC       8/03/2012     250
```

Expected Result

```
ItemName    LastMonthAmt    CurrentMonthAmt

ABC          500             250
```

Please help me to write the query for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

What i have tried is as follows:

```
declare @T table
(
  id varchar(2),
  [Date] datetime,
  [Amt] varchar(5),
  [Status] varchar(5)
)

insert into @T
select '01',   '1/02/12',  '125',   'LM' union all
--select '01',   '1/02/12',  '200',   'Exit' union all
select '01',   '2/02/12',  '250',   'CM' union all
--select '01',   '2/02/12',  '150',  'CM' union all
select '02',   '1/02/12',  '300',   'LM' union all
--select '02',   '1/02/12',  '350',   'CM' union all
--select '02',   '2/02/12',  '220',   'LM' union all
select '02',   '2/02/12',  '140',  'CM'

select id,
       --convert(varchar(8), [Date], 1) as [Date],
       [Amt] as [CM],
      [Amt] as [LM]
from
  (
    select distinct id,
           [Amt],
           row_number() over(partition by id order by [Date] asc) as rn1,
           row_number() over(partition by id order by [Date] desc) as rn2
    from @T
  ) as T
where T.rn1 = 1 or
      T.rn2 = 1
group by id, [Amt]
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you where to show what you have tried people would be more able to help you since Stack Overflow is not site where people write your code for your but rather help you work through problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression similar to this:

```
select itemname,
  sum(case when month(date) = month(getdate()) -1 then amt else 0 end) LastMonthAmt,
  sum(case when month(date) = month(getdate()) then amt else 0 end) CurrentMonthAmt
from yourtable
group by itemname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26591/4)