# How to fetch last month's data for every date in my SQL/Vertica table

Tags: sql, vertica

There were a couple of older posts with similar questions but none cater to my specific requirements including this one ([Current month and last month data in single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297255/current-month-and-last-month-data-in-single-row)).

I have a Vertica table (say CompanyData) with the following columns:

```
company_id | date | shares
```

with the PK being a composite 'company_id,date'.

Now fetching the **previous month's data** for a specific date or range of dates is easy enough, using add_months function. Something like:

```
select * 
from CompanyData 
where company_id = 'ABC12' and date = add_months('20121205', -1) 
order by company_id, date;
```

However, when I want to do the same thing for the entire table (all companies, all dates) a self join is what comes to my mind.

Is there a way to avoid a join and still retrieve this information for the entire table?

Please let me know if you need any further info.

**Sample table data:**

company_id |   date   | shares

ABC12      | 20120101 | 253.77
ABC12      | 20120102 | 253.77
ABC12      | 20120103 | 254.59
ABC12      | 20120104 | 254.12
.
.
.
ABC12      | 20120201 | 257.90
ABC12      | 20120202 | 257.41
.
.
XYZ45      | 20120101 | 312.45
XYZ45      | 20120102 | 314.25
XYZ45      | 20120103 | 311.27
XYZ45      | 20120104 | 314.34
.
.
.
XYZ45      | 20120201 | 315.11
XYZ45      | 20120202 | 316.71                                                                                                               .
.

As mentioned earlier, we have **daily frequency data** for lots of companies.

**Desired output would be something like:**

company_id |   date   | shares

ABC12      | 20120101 | NULL
ABC12      | 20120102 | NULL
.
.
ABC12      | 20120201 | 253.77
ABC12      | 20120202 | 253.77
ABC12      | 20120203 | 254.59
ABC12      | 20120204 | 254.12
.
.
. 
XYZ45      | 20120101 | NULL
XYZ45      | 20120102 | NULL 
.
.
XYZ45      | 20120201 | 312.45
XYZ45      | 20120202 | 314.25
XYZ45      | 20120203 | 311.27
XYZ45      | 20120204 | 314.34

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any projections on this table?

Comment: Yes we do have projections on the table.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select cd.*
from CompanyData cd left outer join
     CompanyData cdprev
     on cd.company_id = cdprev.company_id and
        cdprev.date = add_months(cd.date, -1)
where cd.company_id = 'ABC12' 
order by cd.company_id, cd.date;
```

If you only have one record per month, there might be an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I was looking for something other than a self join, since for a table with billions of rows that can get quite costly. Also, this table stores daily data; and yes monthly would have made my life much simpler allowing me to use Analytics!

Comment: @user2492832 . . . The self-join performance might be better than you think.  It would help if you removed the `*` from the select.  That can really slow down a columnar database.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I wish to add on to my earlier query a bit. Let's say we have another table CompanyPrices that I need to join to CompanyData on the PK to get the 'prices' column. From this resultant dataset if I now wish to extract the previous month's data, what will be the best approach?

Comment: Just to clarify, both shares (from CompanyData) and prices (from CompanyPrices) need to fetched for last month, again for every entry in the joined dataset.